# Pick Winner Lottery test throws; Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I'm writing a Lottery contract that's supposed to accept players, pick a winner and send the funds collected to the winner's address, then start over again.
After running npm run test, the first 5 tests are passing but the "sends money to the winner & resets the players array" test fails, with the error message below.

```
  1) lottery Contract
   sends money to the winner & resets the players array:
 Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
```

Personally, I think the problem is at file Lottery.test.js, on this code snippet because up to this point, everything is running well;

```
await lottery.methods.pickWinner().send({
        from: accounts[0]
    });
```

Other projects files are pasted below to help with the debugging.

**My Lottery.sol file;**

```
    pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address payable[] public players;

    function myLottery() public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .001 ether);
        players.push(payable(msg.sender));
    }

    function random() private view returns(uint){
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, players)));
    }

    function pickWinner() public restricted{
        uint index = random() % players.length;
        players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);  
        players = new address payable[](0);
    }

    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }

    function getPlayers() public view returns (address payable[] memory) {
        return players;
    }
}
```

**compile.js**

```
    const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const solc = require("solc");

const lotteryPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "contracts", "Lottery.sol");
const source = fs.readFileSync(lotteryPath, "utf8");

let input = {
  language: "Solidity",
  sources: {
    [lotteryPath]: {
      content: source,
    },
  },

  settings: {
    outputSelection: {
      "*": {
        "*": ["*"],
      },
    },
  },
};

var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

module.exports = {
  abi: output.contracts[[lotteryPath]]["Lottery"].abi,
  bytecode: output.contracts[[lotteryPath]]["Lottery"].evm.bytecode.object,
};
```

**deploy.js**

```
    const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const { abi, bytecode } = require("./compile");

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    '****myMneumonic*****',
    '****myInfuraNode****'
);

const web3 = new Web3 (provider);

const deploy = async () => {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    console.log('Attempting to deploy from account;', accounts[0]);

    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
    .deploy({ data: bytecode })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '10000000', gasPrice: '2000000000'});

    console.log('Contract deployed to;', result.options.address);
};
deploy();
```

**Lottery.test.js**

```
    const assert = require("assert");
const ganache = require("ganache");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
const { abi, bytecode } = require("../compile");

let accounts;
let lottery;

beforeEach(async () => {
  //get a list of all accounts
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  lottery = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
    .deploy({ data: bytecode })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: "1000000" });
});

describe('lottery Contract', () => {
    it ('deploys a contract', () => {
        assert.ok(lottery.options.address);
    });

    it('allows one account to enter', async () => {
        await lottery.methods.enter().send({
            from: accounts[0],
            value: web3.utils.toWei('0.002', 'ether')
        });

        const players = await lottery.methods.getPlayers().call({
            from: accounts [0]
        });

        assert.equal(accounts[0], players);
        assert.equal(1, players.length);
    });

    it('allows multiple accounts to enter', async () => {
        await lottery.methods.enter().send({
            from: accounts[0],
            value: web3.utils.toWei('0.002', 'ether')
        });

        await lottery.methods.enter().send({
            from: accounts[1],
            value: web3.utils.toWei('0.002', 'ether')
        });

        await lottery.methods.enter().send({
            from: accounts[2],
            value: web3.utils.toWei('0.002', 'ether')
        });

        const players = await lottery.methods.getPlayers().call({
            from: accounts[0]
        });

        assert.equal(accounts[0], players[0]);
        assert.equal(accounts[1], players[1]);
        assert.equal(accounts[2], players[2]);
        assert.equal(3, players.length);
    });

    it('requires a minimum amount of ether to enter', async () => {
        try {
            await lottery.methods.enter().send({
                from: accounts[0],
                value: 200
            });
            assert(false);
        } catch (err) {
            assert(err);
        }
    });

    it ('only manager can call pickWinner', async () => {
        try {
            await lottery.methods.pickWinner().send({
                from: accounts[1],
                value: 200
            });
            assert(false);
        } catch (err) {
            assert(err);
        }
    });

    it('sends money to the winner & resets the players array', async () =>{
        await lottery.methods.enter().send({
            from: accounts[0],
            value: web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether')
        });

        const initialBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);

        await lottery.methods.pickWinner().send({
            from: accounts[0]
        });

        const finalBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);

        const difference = finalBalance - initialBalance;
        console.log(difference);
        assert(difference > web3.utils.toWei('0.8', 'ether'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you actually never set the manager role before you try picking the winner.  It's failing because at the time of calling `pickWinner()` method, your manager address is null, and this would fail from the require statement in your `restricted` modifier. I would also note that allowing the manager role to be set by anyone is probably not something you would want to do.  Instead you should set the manager role inside the contracts constructor upon deploying your contract like so:

```
constructor(){
  manager = msg.sender;
}
```

Then you can get rid of `myLottery()` all together.  Hope this helped.  If you have any other questions feel free to reach out to me on Twitter @_syndk8.